# What is the meaning of MariaDB `mysql`.`servers` table constraint?

Tags: mariadb, constraint, spider

I am using [SPIDER engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/spider-storage-engine-overview/) to access a remote table from within my MariaDB database, which requires a server definition in `mysql.servers` table created via [`CREATE SERVER`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-server/) statement.

I noticed that this table has a column named `Db` of type `char(64)` with a constraint hitting `information_schema.SCHEMATA.SCHEMA_NAME` field.

I was wondering what is the meaning of this, since the database referred by this field might be on a different server? I feel I am missing something but I can't guess what.